# How to create a custom slider with custom selected and unselected images?

Tags: iphone, uislider

I need to create a slider which should have custom images for following slider parts:

1. left round corner image.
2. left part image which is selected part.
3. right part image which is
   unselected or remaining part.
4. right corner image.
5. Thumb image.

Also i want to increase the thickness of the slider.
Please give me some suggestion or share some code snippets.

Thanks,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Look at setThumbImage:forState to change thumb image.

minimumValueImage and maximumValueImage for the images on the left and right hand side of the slider.

The track images can also be manipulated.

See "Customizing the slider's appearance" at http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UISlider_Class/Reference/Reference.html

Comment: I tried this thing and come with a different problem. For more info see the question in this post : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5757556/why-the-slider-is-disappearing