# Why the slider is disappearing?

Tags: iphone, uislider

Here's the code i am using to draw a custom slider but its disappearing when i started dragging it.

```
-(void)addSliderX:frame andminimumValue:(int)min andmaximumValue:(int)max andSliderValue:(int)value{
    CGRect frame1 = CGRectFromString(frame);
    statSlider = [[UISlider alloc]initWithFrame:frame1];
    //[statSlider setMinimumTrackImage:[[UIImage imageNamed:@"greenSlider.png"] stretchableImageWithLeftCapWidth:10.0 topCapHeight:10.0] forState:UIControlStateNormal]; 
    [statSlider setMinimumTrackImage:[[UIImage imageNamed:@"sliderBar_green_stretch.png"] stretchableImageWithLeftCapWidth:10.0 topCapHeight:0.0] forState:UIControlStateNormal]; 
    [statSlider setMaximumTrackImage:[[UIImage imageNamed:@"sliderBar_brown_stretch.png"] stretchableImageWithLeftCapWidth:10.0 topCapHeight:0.0] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [statSlider setThumbImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"sliderBar_greenThumb.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [statSlider setMinimumValue:min];
    [statSlider setMaximumValue:max];
    statSlider.continuous = NO;
    positionX = value;
    UIFont * font  = YEAR_LABEL_FONT;
    [statSlider addTarget:self action:@selector(valueChanged:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventValueChanged];
    [statSlider addTarget:self action:@selector(sliderChanged:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];


    UIView * bubble2 = [[UIView alloc]init];
    UIImageView * back2 = [[UIImageView alloc]initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"sliderBar_handle_number.png"]];
    UILabel * val = [[UILabel alloc]init];
    UIButton * newB = [ApplicationHelpers buttonWithTitle:@"" andBgColor:[UIColor clearColor] andTitleColor:DESC_Color_White andTitleFont:font];

    UIImage *buttonImage2 = [UIImage imageNamed:@"sliderBar_handle_number.png"];
    UIImage *strechableButtonImage2 = [buttonImage2 stretchableImageWithLeftCapWidth:12 topCapHeight:0];
    [newB setBackgroundImage:strechableButtonImage2 forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    bubble2.tag = viewTag +1;
    back2.tag = viewTag + 2;
    val.tag = viewTag + 3; 
    newB.tag = viewTag + 4;
    /*bubble2.alpha = 0;
    back2.alpha = 0;
    val.alpha = 0;*/
    bubble2.hidden = YES;
    back2.hidden = YES;
    val.hidden = YES;

    [self.view addSubview:statSlider]; 
    //[self.view addSubview:bubble2];
    [self.view addSubview:newB];
    [bubble2 addSubview:back2];
    [bubble2 addSubview:val];
}

// create the bubble over slider
-(void)valueChanged:(id)sender{

    UISlider *localSlider = (UISlider *)sender;
    greenSliderValue = [[NSString alloc] initWithString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%3.0f", [localSlider value]]];
    dsp =[greenSliderValue floatValue];
    UIView * bubble2 = (UIView*)[self.view viewWithTag:151186];
    UIButton * newB = (UIButton*)[self.view viewWithTag:151189];

    UIImageView * back2 = (UIImageView*)[bubble2 viewWithTag:151187];
    UILabel * val = (UILabel*)[bubble2 viewWithTag:151188]; 
    NSString *valString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%3.0f", [localSlider value]];    
    [val setText:valString];
    [newB setTitle:valString forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [newB setContentHorizontalAlignment:UIControlContentHorizontalAlignmentCenter];
    UIFont * font  = YEAR_LABEL_FONT;
    val.font = font;
    val.textColor = DESC_Color_White;

    bubble2.hidden = NO;
    back2.hidden = NO;
    val.hidden = NO;
    newB.hidden = NO;
    CGFloat sliderMax = localSlider.maximumValue;
    CGFloat sliderMin = localSlider.minimumValue;

    CGFloat sliderMaxMinDiff = sliderMax - sliderMin;
    CGFloat sliderValue = dsp;
    CGFloat xCoord = 65.0-42.0;
    CGFloat yCoord = (CGFloat)positionX;
    CGFloat halfMax = (sliderMax+sliderMin)/2.0;

    if (sliderValue > halfMax) 
    {
        xCoord = xCoord-(sliderValue-halfMax);
    }
    else 
    {
        xCoord = xCoord + (halfMax-sliderValue);
    }

    xCoord= xCoord + (600/sliderMaxMinDiff)*(sliderValue-sliderMin);
    newB.frame = CGRectMake(xCoord,yCoord,84,47);

}

// Gets activated when slider is moved
-(void)sliderChanged:(id)sender{
    i = i+1;

    UISlider *localSlider = (UISlider *)sender;
    greenSliderValue = [[NSString alloc] initWithString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%3.0f", [localSlider value]]];
    dsp =[greenSliderValue floatValue];

    currentDict = [[totalDict objectForKey:[[totalDict objectForKey:@"Screens"]objectAtIndex:i]]retain];


    NSString * identifier = [currentDict objectForKey:@"identifier"];
    if ([identifier isEqualToString:@"end"]) {

        NSDictionary * completed = [currentDict objectForKey:@"Completed"];
        NSString * frameD = [completed objectForKey:@"Frame"];
        CGRect frame3 = CGRectFromString(frameD);
        NSString * frameString2 = NSStringFromCGRect(frame3);
        NSString * label = [completed objectForKey:@"Dest"];

        [self doneButtons:label andFrame:frameString2];
        [sliderBox removeFromSuperview];
        [yes removeFromSuperview];
        [no removeFromSuperview];
        [next removeFromSuperview];
        [statSlider removeFromSuperview];
        [self estimateButtons:@" Estimate." andFrameX:509 andFrameY:520 andFrameW:234 andFrameH:54];
    }
    else {

        NSDictionary * quest = [currentDict objectForKey:@"Question"];
        NSString * text = [quest objectForKey:@"Text"];
        NSString * frameQ = [quest objectForKey:@"Frame"];
        CGRect frame1 = CGRectFromString(frameQ);
        NSString * frameString = NSStringFromCGRect(frame1);

        if ([identifier isEqualToString:@"Yes"]) 
        {

            NSDictionary * selectable1 = [currentDict objectForKey:@"Selectable1"];
            NSString * frameYes = [selectable1 objectForKey:@"Frame"];
            CGRect frame3 = CGRectFromString(frameYes);
            NSString * frameString3 = NSStringFromCGRect(frame3);

            NSDictionary * selectable2 = [currentDict objectForKey:@"Selectable2"];
            NSString * frameNo = [selectable2 objectForKey:@"Frame"];
            CGRect frame4 = CGRectFromString(frameNo);
            NSString * frameString4 = NSStringFromCGRect(frame4);
            select.hidden = YES;
            [yes removeFromSuperview];
            [no removeFromSuperview];
            [self yesButton:@"  Yes." andFrame:frameString3];
            [self noButton:@"  No." andFrame:frameString4];

        }

        else 
        {
            NSDictionary * selectable = [currentDict objectForKey:@"Selectable"];
            NSString * frameBu = [selectable objectForKey:@"Frame"];
            CGRect frame2 = CGRectFromString(frameBu);
            NSString * frameString1 = NSStringFromCGRect(frame2);
            select.hidden = YES;
            [self selectButtons:@"  Select." andFrame:frameString1 andValue:goal];
        }

        NSDictionary * completed = [currentDict objectForKey:@"Completed"];
        NSString * frameD = [completed objectForKey:@"Frame"];
        CGRect frame3 = CGRectFromString(frameD);
        NSString * frameString2 = NSStringFromCGRect(frame3);
        NSString * label = [completed objectForKey:@"Dest"];

        UIView * bubble2 = (UIView*)[self.view viewWithTag:1];
        UIButton * newB = (UIButton*)[self.view viewWithTag:151189];
        [newB removeFromSuperview];
        [bubble2 removeFromSuperview];
        [greenSliderValue release];
        [statSlider removeFromSuperview];
        [trade removeFromSuperview];

        [sliderBox removeFromSuperview];
        [slidValue removeFromSuperview];
        [next removeFromSuperview];


        [self question:text andFrame:frameString];
        [self doneButtons:label andFrame:frameString2];
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you put break points on "[sliderBox removeFromSuperview]" in -(void)sliderChanged:(id)sender and checked if they are getting hit? - that seems like it could cause the removal of the slider from your container view.